# Assign array elements to an array created in Heap Memory

Tags: arrays, c++11, data-structures, heap-memory

I want to create an array in heap memory with values {5,8,7,6,9}, but I am unable to do so, please tell me what is wrong with this code.
Please tell how to do it without using vectors. I know that using vectors is easier, but I just want to know how to do without it.

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int *p = new int[5];
    p = {5,8,7,6,9};
    int *q = new int[10];
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
        q[i]=p[i];
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Technically, a `std::vector` allocates its memory off the heap as well, and it's much easier to handle (and initialize). And there's no risk of memory leaks (like you have).

Comment: `int *p = new int[5]{5,8,7,6,9};` should work.